# Remember-me not working .. throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, remember-me

Following the guidlines of below tutorial I implemented remember-me functionality

```
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-remember-me
```

But when I run the program it throws **java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required.** whereas UserDetails service is implemented properly. Below is the configure method and registration of userDetailsWebService.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // @formatter:off
     http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/", "/home","/login","/adduser","/verifyemail", 
                 "/baduser", "/resetmypassword","/resetpasswordlink").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/tasks").hasAnyAuthority("APP_USER","APP_TENURED_USER","ADMIN")
         .antMatchers("/resetpasswordpage","/resetpassword").hasAuthority(TaskFirstConstants.RESET_PASSWORD_ACCESS)
         .antMatchers("/resetpasswordpage","/resetpassword").hasRole("")
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and().rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret")     //  -- here
         .and()
     .formLogin()
         .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
         .loginPage("/login")
         .defaultSuccessUrl("/tasks")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
     .logout()
         .permitAll()
         .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService ){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;       
}
```

Complete error log is below ..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSe
curityConfigurerAdapter.java:455) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:1
23) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:130) ~[spring-secu
rity-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:98) ~[sprin
g-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[s
pring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEAS
E.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~
[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.
RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.
2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-we
b-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
 ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4
.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEAS
E]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE
]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10
.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELE
ASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.R
ELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5
.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

To have a look at complete code, please check https://github.com/vikashsaini01/TaskFirst/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well it started to work after I registered `UserDetailsService` for remember me functionality. Using below code..

```
.and()
  .rememberMe()
    .key("uniqueAndSecret")
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
```

as mentioned on https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

> Don’t forget to add your `RememberMeServices` implementation to your `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setRememberMeServices()` property, include the `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider` in your `AuthenticationManager.setProviders()` list, and add `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` into your `FilterChainProxy` (typically immediately after your `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`).

**But I am still not sure why it didn't pick the default from `DaoAuthenticationProvider`... anybody??**

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed the separate userService registration too, but after this fix, it works.